# Trying to store a SpannedString using HTML format

Tags: java, android, html, sqlite, spannable

I am trying to store a SpannedString into an Sqlite3 database, unfortunately, there is no direct way to put it in a ContentValues object. From several other posts, I gathered that the solution is to convert the Spannable string to HTML before writing the DB.
So I have this code (focus on 'name' and 'code', which are CharSequences with styles):

```
    values.put(CATEGORY_COL, category.ordinal());
    values.put(NAME_COL, Html.toHtml(new SpannedString(name),Html.TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_INDIVIDUAL));
    values.put(CODE_COL, Html.toHtml(new SpannedString(code),Html.TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_INDIVIDUAL) );
    values.put(DESCRIPTION_COL, description.toString());
```

The conversion of 'code' to html fails with an exception:

```
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.commodo.aplX, PID: 24921
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at android.text.Html.withinParagraph(Html.java:617)
    at android.text.Html.withinBlockquoteIndividual(Html.java:456)
    at android.text.Html.withinBlockquote(Html.java:403)
    at android.text.Html.withinDiv(Html.java:338)
    at android.text.Html.withinHtml(Html.java:288)
    at android.text.Html.toHtml(Html.java:269)
```

I traced the code with the debugger and found where the exception is being generated. It is in the **Html.java** file, and the offending code tries to get the typeface family name (String returned by **getFamily()**) but it is null, and therefore the exception occurs next line, where **"monospace".equals(null)** .

```
int s = ((StyleSpan) style[j]).getStyle();

if ((s & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
  out.append("<b>");
}
if ((s & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
  out.append("<i>");
}
```

---

```
if (style[j] instanceof TypefaceSpan) {
    String s = ((TypefaceSpan) style[j]).getFamily();
    if ("monospace".equals(s)) {
        out.append("<tt>");
    }
}
```

---

```
if (style[j] instanceof SuperscriptSpan) {
    out.append("<sup>");
}
```

It seems to me this is a bug. I would like to find a bypass for it, or another, not complicated, way of storing spannables in a database.

Comment: Please study [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)